# Duplicate Perl installation on CENTOs 64 bit

Tags: c++, linux, perl, cross-compiling

I insatlled perl on my machine and on giving follows command

```
 perl -e 'print("@INC\n");'
```

I get this output

```
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.1/x86_64-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.1
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.18.1/x86_64-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.18.1 .
```

> But the MACHINE that is working properly gives follows output for the
>   same command

```
/usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl 
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .
```

**YOU CAN SEE THE DIFF INT PATH for lib & lib64**

How can i correct the above ??
please help

Comment: PLEASE DON"T SHOUT IN UPPER CASE.

Comment: How did you install Perl on these two systems?

Answer (score 1):

Perl comes pre-installed on every Linux machine - maybe the *machine that is working properly* uses the stock perl. You can identify the location of the `perl` executable issuing `which perl` in the command line.

Also, you can check the perl version by running `perl -v` - if the perl on the machine that is working is older, it might be the OS perl.

Regarding the ways to manipulate the lib path, have a look at the tutorial that Gabor Szabo wrote regarding [How to change @INC to find Perl modules in non-standard locations](http://perlmaven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations)